# Get the coordinates of a text in a label

Tags: c++, qt

What is the best way to get coordinates of a specific text in a Qlabel? This label is long and spreads over few lines, and I need to get coordinates of a one word somewhere at the end of this label but not at the very end.

Comment: If you mean something like the coordinates of a bounding box for a single word in a QLabel then I can't think of a feasible way to do this. Perhaps if you explain what you want the coordinates for, there may be another way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QWidget::font()` to get the label's font info and pass into a `QFontMetrics`.  You can then use the `boundingRect(....)` methods to get the coordinates of the various words in your string.